# How to create phpfox plugin

Tags: php, phpfox

I am developing to implement a profile information plugin in a [phpfox](http://www.phpfox.com/) website.

I don't know how to create a plugin in phpfox.

How can I create a new plugin in phpfox?

Answer (score 2):

From the Admin Control Panel, Extensions->Plugins->Create New Plugin

Answer (score 0):

For creating a new plugin you have to create a product(from the administration Control Panel, Extensions->Product->Create New Product) then create a module(from the administration Control Panel, Extensions->Module->Create New Module) and then create your plugin.
For complete detail you can check their site.